# Can I take this derivative?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I'm trying to solve this question in the classical [Do Carmo's differential geometry book](http://www.math.uni.lodz.pl/~maczar/ggk/do%20Carmo,%20Differential%20Geometry%20of%20Curves%20and%20Surfaces.pdf) (page 23):

> 5. A regular parametrized curve $\alpha$ has the property that all its tangent lines pass through a fixed point. Prove that the trace of $\alpha$ is a (segment of a) a straight line.

Following the statement of the question, we have $\alpha(s)+\lambda(s)\alpha'(s)=const$.

Taking the derivative of both sides we have $\alpha'(s)+\lambda'(s)\alpha'(s)+\lambda(s)\alpha''(s)=0$ which is equal to $(1+\lambda'(s))\alpha'(s)+\lambda(s)\alpha''(s)=0$.

So before I continue my attempt of solution I realized that maybe I can't take this derivative above because I don't know if $\lambda$ is differentiable.

Can I take the derivative above?

Comment: @M.Winter the derivative is taken with respect to $s$. I replace the variable $t$ by $s$ cause this curve is parametrized by arc length.

Comment: @M.Winter I'm sorry, just a typo. Thank you for the remark!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you were only given a *regular* parametrized curve, not an arclength-parametrized curve, although of course you could reparametrize by arclength. But what regularity tells you is that $\alpha'(t)\cdot\alpha'(t) > 0$ for all $t$.

So let's take your equation $$\alpha(t)+\lambda(t)\alpha'(t) = P,$$ 
where $P$ is a constant vector, and subtract $\alpha(t)$ from both sides. Now dot with $\alpha'(t)$ and we get $$\lambda(t) = \frac{(P-\alpha(t))\cdot\alpha'(t)}{\|\alpha'(t)\|^2}.$$
The denominator is never $0$, and both numerator and denominator are smooth functions of $t$, so $\lambda$ is likewise a smooth function of $t$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please give me a little bit more of information how you got the last expression of $\lambda(t)$?

Comment: It's in the words :) Subtract $\alpha(t)$ from both sides, so you get $\lambda(t)\alpha'(t)=P-\alpha(t)$, and then dot with $\alpha'(t)$. ... By the way, my earlier comment really applies to you! Make sure you denote constant *vectors* and constant *scalars* so that you'll know which is which.

Comment: thank you for the warning, I should have paid more attention to the earlier answer of the other user

Comment: Yes, PLEASE do not divide vectors by vectors!! :P By the way, you might find my differential geometry text (which you can download by clicking the link in my profile) a bit more explicit and concrete than doCarmo's.

Comment: Thank you again, I'll read it as a complement to Do carmo's book :)

Answer (score 1):

Because $\|\alpha'(s)\|\not=0$, you can scalar multiply by $\alpha'(s)$ and rearrange for $\lambda(s)$:

$$\lambda(s)=\frac{\mathrm{const}-\langle\alpha(s),\alpha'(s)\rangle}{\|\alpha'(s)\|^2}.$$

As everything on the right is differentiable (assuming $\alpha\in C^2$), so is $\lambda(s)$.

Comment: This is nonsense. You cannot divide a vector by a vector.

Comment: @TedShifrin Right. I am sorry. I would delete my answer but OP has to remove the acceptance first.

Comment: There is a far better way to do this. Use dot product.

Comment: Much better. However, it would be better to distinguish between constant *vectors* and constant *scalars*. Writing "const" can be very ambiguous and lead to errors.